# Multi-List Options Group

Tags: sitecore-forms

With Sitecore Forms 9, how to Group options in  multi-select list box?

Comment: Could you be more specific with preferably also with some illustration? Your question can be interpreted in various ways.

Comment: Just Like <optgroup><option1>....</optgroup>

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make a custom form element.

The fieldtype itself is quite easy to make following Sitecore's documentation: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/sitecore_forms/setting_up_and_configuring/walkthrough_creating_a_custom_form_element

Creating a good editor is a bit harder, if you want to make the options inside the Forms interface. But if you could use an external datasource (such as an item hierarchy somewhere in the solution) it should be easier to just point at the root for this hierarchy. Here's some inspiration for making a fieldtype with external Hierarchy for building up the control:
https://mortenengel.blogspot.com/2018/06/fifa-world-cup-part-2-of-4.html